# Can I delete some folders of nokogiri and capybara-webkit inside of my rvm gemset?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, nokogiri, capybara-webkit

I was using a disk analyzer and I noticed in my `.rvm` folder two gems, `nokogiri` and `capybara-webkit`, bigger than the usual:

[image]

Checking inside of them I found that for nokogiri there is a temp folder and for capybara-webkit a source folder.

[image]

My question is: Is it safe to delete these folders?(Yeah, I'm a greedy disk space saver) and why nokogiri is creating that temporary folder? Because I have another gemset (with a lower version of ruby and nokogiri) and there isn't creating that folder.

[image]

Comment: What's the software you're using to check this?

Comment: @PedroNascimento It's [baobab](http://www.marzocca.net/linux/baobab/figures/baobab_fullscan.png) or commonly known as "Disk Usage Analyzer" in Linux

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22319146/remove-unnecessary-temporary-files-after-gem-install-nokogiri/22432408#22432408

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can remove the tmp directory.

If you don't have a new-enough version of libxml2 or libxslt nokogiri downloads and builds it for you to link against.  Unfortunately RubyGems doesn't ask the nokogiri to clean up after itself at this time, so these build artifacts are left around.

Comment: Nokogiri should be cleaning up after itself (I'm the maintainer). I've created a GitHub issue to track this work:

https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/970

Answer (score 1):

I don't really have an answer, but if it were me I'd move the folder(s) aside, test my apps or whatever, then delete if stuff still works.

Comment: I wanted +1 and -1 at the same time ... this should be a comment