# Remove unnecessary temporary files after gem install nokogiri

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, nokogiri

I have to use [nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) for some xml processing.
For this I create a rvm gemset specific to the project and install nokogiri by gem install nokogiri. No problems this far.

But when I look into ~.rvm/gems/ruby-...@nokogiri/gems/nokogiri-.../ext/nokogiri/ and its subfolders I see files worth of 140MB in the filesystem.

Is there some generic way of removing this cruft?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "generic way". Note that the current situation is considered [a bug](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/970) by the Nokogiri maintainer.

Answer (score 2):

That's slightly larger than what I get. I see 108MB on OS X, with the major offenders being 88MB in `ext`, 18MB in `ports`, 750k in `test` and 520k in `lib`.

In `ext/nokogiri` you certainly don't need the 87MB of `tmp` directory. So that's a major savings right there.

```
phrogz$ pwd
/Users/phrogz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/nokogiri-1.6.1

phrogz$ du -sh .
 108M     .

phrogz$ rm -rf ext/tmp
phrogz$ du -sh .
 21M     .
```

Then again, you also don't need any of the source, header, or compiled files in there, either:

```
phrogz$ cd ext/nokogiri/
phrogz$ rm *.c *.h *.o
phrogz$ cd ../../
phrogz$ du -sh .
 20M     .
```

I'm pretty sure you don't need the `ports/archives` directory, which contains the `.tar.gz` source of libxml2 and libxslt:

```
phrogz$ rm -rf ports/archives/
phrogz$ du -sh .
 12M     .
```

And then there's a few megs of documentation for the libraries you can remove for sure:

```
phrogz$ rm -rf ports/x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0/libxml2/2.8.0/share/doc/
phrogz$ rm -rf ports/x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0/libxml2/2.8.0/share/gtk-doc/
phrogz$ rm -rf ports/x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0/libxslt/1.1.26/share/doc/
phrogz$ du -sh .
 4.4M     .
```

You could probably pare it down further, removing things like the `test` directory. But now you've made a huge dent in the problem.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Altough I would really like to go in a more general direction then cleaning up after gem myself.

Comment: @Gizmomogwai Then simply wait until RubyGems is fixed to provide the necessary hooks, and the Nokogiri gem is fixed to remove the post-build garbage.

Comment: Also (untested) I *think* that Nokogiri will only make these huge amounts of files if it has to build libxml2 and libxslt itself. If you have the appropriate version installed locally on the machine, it will not build them.

Comment: Thanks Phrogz ... what should I do now with your answer ... add it as accepted? Or is a duplicate kind of worthless to accept?

Comment: @Gizmomogwai As I don't believe it solved your exact desires, I would not accept it. If it helped you, perhaps upvote (if you haven't already).

Comment: Thanks for the netiquette suggestion ... already upvoted.